# ‘::at_quick_exit’ has not been declared

Tags: c++, c++11

I have installed c++11 (version 4.8.2).

During compilation I am getting an error:

> In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2
>   /bits/basic_string.h:2815,
>                    from /usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/string:52,
>                    from Main.cpp:1:
>
> ::at_quick_exit’ has not been declared.

I tried to search this problem but I didn't find a solution.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably you meant gcc 4.8.2, did you pass the `-std=c++11` flag when compiling?

Comment: yes i am passing `-std=c++11`

Comment: Are you including <cstdlib> or <stdlib.h> (the former will need to be used in std:: namespace)

Comment: `at_quick_exit` is `ifdef`ed using [`_GLIBCXX_HAVE_AT_QUICK_EXIT`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/c_std/cstdlib;h=fa3e0ead9774724e72ec2367a5b27133ae51e3ec;hb=9bcca88e24e64d4e23636aafa3404088b13bcb0e), perhaps your c library doesn't support it.

Comment: @user657267, might be my c library doesn't support it .. i am re-installing a latest version. Thanks.