# ::at_quick_exit error with c++11 enabled

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

I've been compiling a very simple 'hello, world' program on a ubuntu 14.04 but failed strangely. The problem is I can't compile a simple hello world program with option -std=c++11.

```
#include<iostream>

int main(void){
  std::cout << “hello, world!” << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried g++ version 4.8.4, 4.9.3, 5.3.0, and clang++ version 3.4. When I compile it with the commands like `g++-5 -o main main.cpp -std=c++11`, they all failed with the same errors :(this example is generated by g++-5)

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:5251,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/cstdlib:126:11: error: ‘::at_quick_exit’ has not been declared
   using ::at_quick_exit;
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/cstdlib:149:11: error: ‘::quick_exit’ has not been declared
   using ::quick_exit;
           ^
```

But if I compile it with this command: `clang++ -o main main.cpp -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`, everything goes fine. So I suspect there must be some issue with my libstdc++ related headers. Currently I have the following packages installed (generated with `dpkg -l | grep libstdc++`):

```
ii  libstdc++-4.8-dev:amd64                               4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1                              amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
ii  libstdc++-4.9-dev:amd64                               4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04                                amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
ii  libstdc++-5-dev:amd64                                 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04                                amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
ii  libstdc++6:amd64                                      5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04                                amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3
ii  libstdc++6:i386                                       5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04                                i386         GNU Standard C++ Library v3
```

I found this same issue here:[‘::at_quick_exit’ has not been declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227601/at-quick-exit-has-not-been-declared)
The third reply of it says "`at_quick_exit` is `ifdefed` using `_GLIBCXX_HAVE_AT_QUICK_EXIT`, perhaps your c library doesn't support it." I think he's right, but I don't know how to solve this problem. Could anybody help?

Comment: Is this a fresh installation of Ubuntu or did the problem start after installing/upgrading certain packages?

Comment: By the way, there are no **official** gcc-5 packages for Ubuntu 14.04. Where from did you install these packages? They might not be compatible with your system. You might want to purge them and try again.

Comment: Your code uses `“` instead of `"`, is this a transcription error?